# dockerd not restarting at reboot with message "failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start"

Tags: docker

First post here so apologize for any error.

I have a docker environment that exhibits a really strange problem.
It used to work flawlessly when I was on 18.09.2 but then I needed to upgrade docker version as it was needed for some dockers, due to change in API version ( IIRC ).

I've ugraded to 20.10.2 ( without reboot ) and everything seemed to be ok, dockers starts and I can use them .
After some time I had a power failure that lead me to a reboot and since then I have the problem.
At boot dockers command results in :

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Thus I've searched in logs ( /var/log/docker.log ) and found:

```
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.702266553+02:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.715505120+02:00" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.728188524+02:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=9883
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.728497763+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.728564781+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.728723243+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.728841483+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.813209337+02:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b version=1.4.3
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.928783093+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.929009055+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.936721860+02:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Modu
le aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.65-v7l-sarpi4\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.936880396+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.937437133+02:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (ext4) 
must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.937510744+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.937618391+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.937684465+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.937796094+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938041796+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938477682+02:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a z
fs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938549200+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938622793+02:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938674255+02:00" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.938972068+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939055994+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939191530+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939374825+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939489232+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939557250+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939634268+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939699008+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939768008+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939834674+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.939925785+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
time="2021-08-30T16:40:11.940284968+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
time="2021-08-30T16:40:12.729504178+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc 
= \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:15.081866772+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc 
= \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:18.723223037+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc 
= \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
time="2021-08-30T16:40:23.950263284+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc 
= \"transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start
```

I've banged my head to wall and finally I've found that if I remove the

```
/var/run/docker/containerd
```

directory I can start dockerd and containerd without any issue, but obviously loosing every docker instance and need to docker rm and docker start my containers again.

Do you have any idea why this happens ?

My environment:

```
root@casa:/var/adm/packages# cat /etc/slackware-version 
Slackware 14.2+
root@casa:/var/adm/packages# uname -a
Linux casa.pigi.org 5.4.65-v7l-sarpi4 #3 SMP Mon Sep 21 10:13:26 BST 2020 armv7l BCM2711 GNU/Linux
root@casa:/var/adm/packages# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 5
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 9
 Server Version: 20.10.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc version: 
 init version: fec3683 (expected: de40ad0)
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.65-v7l-sarpi4
 Operating System: Slackware 14.2 arm (post 14.2 -current)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.738GiB
 Name: casa.pigi.org
 ID: HF4Y:7TDZ:O5GV:HM7H:YCVS:CLKW:GNOM:6PSA:XRCQ:3BQU:TZ3P:URLD
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: pigi102
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No blkio weight support
WARNING: No blkio weight_device support

root@casa:/var/adm/packages# runc -v
runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev

root@casa:/var/adm/packages# /usr/bin/docker -v
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

root@casa:/var/adm/packages# containerd -v
containerd github.com/containerd/containerd 1.4.3 269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b

docker-proxy-20201215_fa125a3
```

Thanks in advance.

Pigi_102

Answer (score -1):

I did some more tests, and it seems that if I run containerd ( with all the option and flags as dockerd does ) and wait long enough it eventually starts and from there on dockerd is able to start.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

I manage to fix my problems by downgrading to docker 19.03.15 and containerd 1.2.13
With these versions everything is working as expected.

Pigi